# Data from Poller not displaying inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Simple issue i believe but i cant seem to figure it out since i am still new. I have a poller setup to query my file and it should display inside my partial but it does not here is the code:

Also this setup should update the Partial with New Data every 1 second correct? so when i add a new data to the file.

```
app.factory('Poller', function($http, $timeout) {

var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };

var poller = function () {
  $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getProjects.php')
  .then(function(r) {
    data.response = r.data;
    data.calls++;
    $timeout(poller, 1000);
  });
};
poller();

return {
  data: data.response
};

});

app.controller('openProjectsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'projectsModal', 'Poller',
function ($scope, $http, projectsModal, Poller) {

  $scope.data = Poller.data;

}]);

<li class="list-item" data-ng-repeat="project in data | orderBy:'Posted' : true">
    <div data-ng-click="showModal(project.uid)">
        <h4>{{project.Title}}</h4>
        <span>{{project.Skills}}</span><br/>
        <div>
            <span>{{project.Budget}}</span>
            <span class="pull-right timestamp">{{project.Posted|timeago}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Sample Json file:

```
{ 
"item": [
{
    "uid"   : "1",
    "Title" : "Thing",
    "Offers": "0",
    "Skills": "1,2,3",
    "Posted": "June 17, 2015 13:30:00",
    "Budget": "$250"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Do you get a response from server when polling? Can you post the JSON response? What kind of library/module is `ngModal`? Where do you set the controller?

Comment: Please disregard ng-modal directive as i am not using it right now. i will update the json in a sec.

Comment: `var data = { response: {}, calls: 0 };` should be `var data = { response: [], calls: 0 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plunker [http://plnkr.co/edit/VMXN58uIrmfYRUgydtbr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VMXN58uIrmfYRUgydtbr?p=preview)

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('openProjectsCtrl', openProjectsCtrl);

openProjectsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Poller'];

function openProjectsCtrl($scope, Poller) {
  $scope.data = Poller.data;
}

angular.module('app')
    .factory('Poller', Poller);

Poller.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout'];

function Poller($http, $timeout) {

var data = { response: [], calls: 0 };

var json = [{
  "id": 1,
  "Skills": "Marketing Assistant",
  "Budget": "$5.66",
  "Posted": "7/14/2014"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "Skills": "Paralegal",
  "Budget": "$6.43",
  "Posted": "9/7/2014"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "Skills": "Statistician II",
  "Budget": "$5.06",
  "Posted": "2/10/2015"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "Skills": "Payment Adjustment Coordinator",
  "Budget": "$3.42",
  "Posted": "1/19/2015"
}];


var poller = function () {
  // $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getProjects.php')
  // .then(function(r) {
    // data.response = r.data;
    // data.calls++;
    // $timeout(poller, 1000);
  // });
  angular.copy(json, data.response);
};

poller();

return {
  data: data.response
};
}
})();
```

Comment: Hey sorry this is dumb of me but i cant get this to work with the $http.get instead of the json var you have. Can you tell me what needs to be changed for that to happen?

Comment: yep, just remove my json and instead of this `angular.copy(json, data.response);` put this `angular.copy(r.data, data.response);` and uncomment what I commented

Comment: Move `angular.copy(r.data, data.response);` inside the response (one line up)

Comment: Great that is setting the data inside the factory but inside the controller the data does not arrive when i use console.log and as such not displayed on my view?

Comment: Actually i fixed that my adding r.data.projects :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you do navigate to the 'item' object?

Try:

```
return {
  data: data.response.item;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your service like this

```
app.factory('Poller', function($http) {

return {
      poll: function () {
              return $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers /php/getProjects.php');
           }  
       }
});
```

Use it in your controller like this

```
app.controller('openProjectsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'projectsModal',   'Poller','$interval'
function ($scope, $http, projectsModal, Poller,$interval) {

 $interval(function(){
     Poller.poll().success(function(response){
        $scope.data=response.data;
     }).error(function(error){
        //handle error here
     })},1000);
}]);
```

Comment: To get a clear picture I need to know the response that you receive for this request.Is it the same JSON that you have written for your file.You can log the response in your console and see